# Ionic LocalStorage Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im working on an app called "Workaholic" and this app features a To Do List. 
So The Problem that i have is that i dont know how i should add the localStorage. It would be awesome, if you could tell me where i should add the localStorage and how. I read through the docs for localStorage on the Ionic Page but i dont know how. Heres the Code!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Workaholic</h1>
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-android-home" href="#/home"></a>
    <a class="button button-icon ion-compose icon" href="#/newtask"></a>
    </ion-header-bar>


      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>



            <!-- todolist page -->
            <script id="templates/todo.html" type="text/ng-template">
                <ion-view view-title="todo">
                <ion-content>
                <ion-list ng-init="todoList()">
                <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks" on-hold="edit(task)" on-double-tap="tasks.splice($index, 1)">
                 {{task.title}}
                </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
                </ion-content>
                </ion-view>
              </script>

              <!-- Page to add a Task in Todo -->
            <script id="templates/newtask.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-view view-title="TaskAdd">
                <ion-content class="padding">
                    <div class="tasktitle">
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a Task Title" ng-model="todo.title">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="taskdesc">
                        <label class="item item-input">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a Description to the Task" ng-model="todo.desc">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button ng-click="saveTask(todo)" class="button button-block button-positive"> Save </button>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
            </script>

              <!-- countdown page -->
              <script id="templates/countdown.html" type="text/ng-template">
              <ion-view view-title="countdown">
              <ion-content ng-controller="CountCtrl">
              <div class="countdown" ng-show="countDown&gt;0"><span ng-if="minutes &lt; 10">0</span>{{minutes}}:<span ng-if="seconds &lt; 10">0</span>{{seconds}}</div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="spacer">
                      </div>
                  <div class="firstInp">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                      <input class="firstInp" id="input1" name="myform" ng-model="mininputVal" type="tel" placeholder="Min.">
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="secondInp">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input class="secondInp" id="input2" name="myform" ng-model="secinputVal" type="tel" placeholder="Sec.">
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="countButton1">
                    <button id="countDownbutton" ng-disabled="countDown > 0 || !secinputVal" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="timerCountdown(mininputVal, secinputVal)">Start Countdown</button>
                    </div>
                  <div class="countButton2">
                    <button id="countDownbutton" ng-disabled="!countDown" class="button button-assertive" ng-click="stopCount()">Stop Countdown</button>
                  </div>
            </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
            </script>

            <!-- Home Site -->
            <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-view view-title="home">
                <ion-content class="padding">
                    <h4>Hello User! Thank you for testing my App. <br />
                    Its not Finished at all, so if you have <br />
                    improvements or Ideas, just tell me them. <br />
                    <br />
                    </h4>
                    <h4>
                    Contact me: <br />
                    via Twitter - @JulianTheDev <br />
                    via Email - julianbe00@gmail.com <br />
                    </h4>

                    <a class="button button-block icon-right ion-chevron-right button-assertive button-custom" href="#/todo">To Do's</a>
                    <a class="button button-block icon-right ion-chevron-right button-assertive button-custom" href="#/countdown">Countdown</a>
                    <a class="button button-block icon-right ion-chevron-right button-assertive button-custom" href="#/help">Help</a>
                </ion-content>
              </ion-view>
              </script>

            <!-- How It Works Site -->
            <script id="templates/help.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-view view-title="help">
                <ion-content>
                    <div class="todohelp">
                    <h3>To Do</h3>
                    <h4>• Double Tap to delete a Task!</h4>
                    <h4>• Hold on the Task to edit it!</h4>
                    </div>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
            </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })
  .state('help', {
    url: '/help',
    templateUrl: 'templates/help.html'
  })
  .state('countdown', {
    url: '/countdown',
    templateUrl: 'templates/countdown.html'
  })
  .state('newtask', {
      url: '/newtask',
      templateUrl: 'templates/newtask.html'
  })
  .state('todo', {
    url: '/todo',
    templateUrl: 'templates/todo.html'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");

});

app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $ionicListDelegate, $state) {

    // Tasks are stored here
    $scope.tasks =
      [
        {title: "Double Tap To Delete a Task!", description: "Its Just an Example!"},
        {title: "Hold On The Task to Edit It!", description: "Its Just an Example! You can delete this."},
      ];

      window.localStorage['todos'] = JSON.stringify($scope.tasks);

      var todos = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['todos'] || '{}');

      $scope.saveTask = function(todo){
          console.log(todo.title, todo.desc);
          $state.go('todo');
          $scope.tasks.push({title: todo.title});;
      };

// Edits a Task
    $scope.edit = function(task) {
      $scope.data = { response: task.title };
      $ionicPopup.prompt({
        title: "Edit Task",
        scope: $scope
      }).then(function(res) {    // promise 
        if (res !== undefined) task.title = $scope.data.response;
        $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
      })
    };
})


// Countdown Controller
app.controller('CountCtrl', function countController($scope, $interval, $ionicPopup){
    $scope.countDown = 0; // number of seconds remaining
    var stop;
    $scope.mininputVal = "";
    $scope.secinputVal = "";
    $scope.minutes = $scope.mininputVal*60;
    $scope.seconds = $scope.secinputVal;

    // Countdown
    $scope.timerCountdown = function(minutes, seconds) {
        $scope.buttonclick = document.getElementById('countDownbutton')
        $scope.minutes = parseInt(minutes);
        $scope.seconds = parseInt(seconds);

        // Minutes/Seconds Flow + if above the limit
        if ($scope.mininputVal > 99){
            $scope.minutes = 99
        }
        if ($scope.secinputVal > 60){
            $scope.seconds = 60
        }
        if (!$scope.mininputVal){
        $scope.minutes = 0;
        }
        if (!$scope.secinputVal){
        $scope.seconds = 0;
        }
      // set number of seconds until the countdown is ready
      $scope.countDown =  parseInt($scope.mininputVal*60) + parseInt($scope.secinputVal);

      // start the countdown
      stop = $interval(function() {

        // decrement remaining seconds
        $scope.seconds--;
        $scope.countDown--;
        if ($scope.seconds === -1){
            $scope.seconds = 59;
            $scope.minutes--;
        }

        // Stop The Countdown
        $scope.stopCount = function () {
                //Set the Timer stop message.
                console.log("Timer Stopped.")
                //Cancel the Timer.
                if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
                    $interval.cancel(stop);
                    $scope.countDown = 0;
                }
            };

        // if zero, stop $interval and show the popup
        if ($scope.countDown === 0){
          $interval.cancel(stop);
          $scope.running = false;
          console.log("Finished");
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: 'The Countdown is Finished!',
             template: 'Youre Ready To Go!'});
        }
      },1000,0); // invoke every 1 second
    };
});

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `ngStorage` module

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngStorage'])
```

In controller inject `$localStorage`

```
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $ionicListDelegate, $state,$localStorage) ...
```

[Github link-Documentation](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

[Demo example-ref doc](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview)

Comment: do i have to add ng-init to the ion-item so it can get it?

Comment: No there is no need to add ng-init ,since $localStorage in controller ..you can set what you want

Comment: Awesome, i test it now, if i need anymore help, could you help me?

Comment: Dude youre awesome! It worked, finally. It took me about 3 Weeks to get around with localStorage, thank you so much!

Comment: Gr8. I would recommend go through basic examples of ionic or angularJS first over internet

Comment: Yes, i think the biggest problem about my project is, that im very new to angular and ionic and really need to learn the basics :D

Answer (score 1):

this is my Factory for the Localstorage

```
.factory('Ls', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        Set: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },
        Get: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        },
        SetObject: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        },
        GetObject: function (key) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
        },
        ClearLsValues: function (arrKeys) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arrKeys.length; i++) {
                localStorage.removeItem(arrKeys[i]);
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

You can simply use it like this

```
.controller('YourCtrl', ['Ls', function(Ls){
    //Sets a single value
    Ls.Set('name', true);
    //returns the previous set value
    var value = Ls.Get('name');
    //sets an object
    Ls.SetObject('name2', {key:'value'});
    //returns the previous set Object
    var value2 = Ls.GetObject('name2');
    //Clears all values in the Array
    Ls.ClearLsValues(['name', 'name2']);
}])
```

Comment: do i have to add something like ng-init to get it to the list or will it do it automatically? or can i just edit it and it will work just as fine?

Comment: Thats weird what happens when you do console.log(window.localStorage)?